# Unable to convert AsyncTask to retrofit2 in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to convert the following code(java) to post request with retrofit2 in kotlin, However, I find the retrofit2 documentation difficult to understand. I've tried to use @POST and send the request but failed. It would be a great help if you can give me some hints or examples.I would love to hear from pros like you!

This is the type of request I want to send

```
curl -X POST https://api.a3rt.recruit-tech.co.jp/talk/v1/smalltalk \
-F "apikey=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" \
-F "query=test"
```

The following is the actual code I want to convert to retrofit2

```
public class TalkAysncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private static final String API_KEY = YOUR API KEY;
    private static final String API_URL = 
        "https://api.a3rt.recruit-tech.co.jp/talk/v1/smalltalk";

    interface Callback{
        void onReturn(String s);
    }

    private Callback callback;

    TalkAysncTask(Context context){
        callback = (Callback) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("apikey", API_KEY)
                .add("query", params[0])
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(API_URL)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();

        try{
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            return response.body().string();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.d("debug", s);
        callback.onReturn(s);
    }
}
```

I want to know how to get the following type fo response as well

```
{
    status: 200,
    message: "ok",
    results: [{
        perplexity: 2.3688167429546714,
        reply: "tested"
    }],
}
```

I tried to use the following code but didn't work

```
interface AiClient {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/talk/v1/smalltalk")
    fun request(@Field("apikey") apiKey: String,
                @Field("query") query: String?): Call<ApiResponse>

    companion object {
        fun create(): AiClient {
            val retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.a3rt.recruit-tech.co.jp")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
            return retrofit.create(AiClient::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using `OkHttp` in `asycTask`? you can use just `enqueue` function.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But it's my old code. And What I want to do now is to know how to send the post in retrofit2 and get the response data in kotlin

Comment: Post your ApiResponse as well. And your base url should end with a `/`.

Comment: If you are talking about the response from the retrofit2, then I'm unable to, that is why I'm having trouble. I added the type of response that you can get if your request is successful in the above description.

Comment: `ApiResponse` what is this?

Comment: ApiResponse is just a setter and getter class for the response. data class ApiResponse(val message:String, val results: Result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a model class:

```
class ApiResponse(var status:Int, var message:String, var results:MutableList<Results>){
class Results(var perplexity:Double,var reply:String)
}
```

Change your AiClient:

```
interface  AiClient {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("talk/v1/smalltalk")
fun request(@Field("apikey") apiKey: String,
            @Field("query") query: String?): retrofit2.Call<ApiResponse>

companion object {
    fun create(): AiClient {
        val retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.a3rt.recruit-tech.co.jp/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
        return retrofit.create(AiClient::class.java)
    }
}
}
```

To call the Api:

```
AiClient.create().request("yourkey","yourquery").enqueue(object :Callback<ApiResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ApiResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ApiResponse>, response: Response<ApiResponse>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                var result=response.body()
                if (result!=null){
                    result.message
                }


            }

        }
    })
}
```